# C# Update statment failed Error: _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532459699

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method which updates a table as below :

```
  public static Boolean updateRequest(String _VUserName, DateTime newToDate)
{
    SqlConnection conn = getConnection();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE Requests SET [To] = @ToDate FROM Requests INNER JOIN "+
                  "VUsers ON Requests.UserRef = VUsers.VUserID WHERE (VUsers.VUserName = @VUserName)";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToDate", newToDate);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VUserName", _VUserName);

    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;

    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

but it failed with _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532459699 exception

any help?

Comment: that error does not seem to be related at all with the code you pasted

Comment: the same statment works well in sql query analyzer

Comment: see http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/151085/337082.aspx its possible that you have a schema conflict, for example, some of the column values might be null in a non-null column

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following [link](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/151085/337082.aspx) "SQL Server refusing to add a record because it didn't conform to table column specifications"

It looks like it has to do with your update statement. Rather rewrite it like this.

`"UPDATE Requests SET [To] = @ToDate WHERE ...`